# HttpClient Corrupted images

Tags: c#, httpclient

Hi I am downloading images from web using c# HttpClient and storing them in temp folder, but all of them seems to be corrupted. The code I am using is below

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
            { 
                using (
                    Stream contentStream = await (await httpClient.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                    stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,256000,true))
                {
                    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The above code getting and storing images as 7KB but the actual downloaded images using browser is only 2KB.
Any idea what is  wrong with that code?

Comment: You didn't even check what data you receive before writing to disk? Try force opening the 7KB "image" with text editor. It could be some text-based error responses.

Comment: It will help if you provide exact url of image in question.